# raft: state is not determined

Tags: distributed-system, consensus, raft

1. assume a cluster with 7 nodes **N1, N2, ...N7**, with state `x=2`
2. assume **N1** is the leader node
3. then a client send `x=5` to leader node **N1**, and **N1** replicate `x=5` to node **N6 and N7(uncommitted)**, but **N2~N5 didn't receive this RPC**
4. at this moment, **N1 crashed**, so, a new election triggered, my question is bellow:

   - if **N6 win this election**, the state in cluster will be `x=5`(uncommitted will become committed)
   - if **N2 win this election**, the state in cluster will be `x=2`(uncommitted in N6/N7 will be discard)

Did I misunderstand something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, depending on who becomes leader the inflight uncommitted entries may get committed, or may get dropped.